# How can i store data on node site in nuxt application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

I have regular application based on Nuxt and Node. Is it even possible to store data in something like object on node side?
For example, I fetch some news on `fetch` hook, then save the news item in `store` and render it in template. Alongside i wanna save it in client-side store, i do save the news item in node store. So next time, when i fetch some news, i check if there is some news in node.

Pseudocode:

```
// check for news item existence in node storage
let newsItem = node.data.news.find(nodeDataNewsItem => nodeDataNewsItem.alias === route.alias)

// fetch the news item by route alias if it doesn't exists in node storage
if (!newsItem) await fetchNewsItem(route.alias)
```

So, basically i need some kind of node storage.

P.S.
I can't use local storage, cookies and other browser things.

Comment: There are far too many way of doing this to answer the question. Look into things like localstorage, service workers, node in-memory databases.

Comment: Can you give some examples, please?

Comment: Apologies, but what you're looking for could fill multiple books. I recommend posting on a forum if you want direction, or reading blog posts on the subject. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask